# Is there a way to compare three lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, integer, comparison

I am writing a prolog program for a practice assignment where I would like to Write a predicate called sum(A,B,C) where A, B and C are lists of integers and prolog will return true if:

The elements in the concatenated list BC (i.e. lists B and C are “glued together”) form a permutation of the elements in A; and The sum of all integers in B equals the sum of all integers in C.

If anyone with more experience in prolog can give me some advice on how to get this done, that would be nice. I dont really know where to start. I would like to give an input like sum([1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1]). And prolog would return true. However, take, for example, sum([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,3,2]), this would return false since in this example lists 2 and 3 are not a different ordering(permutation) of the numbers of list1, and the sum of the integers in list 3 is not equal to the sum of the integers in list 2.

Any ideas or suggestions for the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. :) Turn your specification into code directly and then work out the details:

```
sum(A, B, C) :- 
    append(B, C, BC),
    permutation(A, BC), 
    sumlist(B, Sum),
    sumlist(C, Sum).
```

This already reveals an ambiguity in your specification: you take care to explain that B and C must be concatenated to form a permutation of A, but that isn't the case for your example `sum([1,2,3], [3,2,1], [2,3,1])`. If your code is closer to the truth than your words, your specification should instead be:

```
sum(A, B, C) :- 
    permutation(A, B), 
    permutation(A, C),
    sumlist(B, Sum),
    sumlist(C, Sum).
```

Now you're in luck because both `sumlist/2` and `permutation/2` already exist. So the program is complete and you haven't had to do anything yet except translate your natural language specification into a Prolog specification!

I should note though that there is no scenario where a permutation of a list will sum to a different value. At least, not in theory, and in practice, only if you are using floating point numbers would you find that to be the case.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation and code! this is already very useful. however, when I used the code on the input sum([1,2,3], X, Y). I would have liked to get a result of:

X = [1,2],
Y = [3];
X = [2,1],
Y = [3];
X = [3],
Y = [1,2];
X = [3],
Y = [2,1].
 but I got the result:
X = Y, Y = [1, 2, 3] .

Any thoughts on how to change the code to get the right output?

Comment: I'm guessing I need to use append.

Comment: @PervySage I can imagine how to do that; that's what the first solution I give does. I cannot imagine how to make it work for that example _and_ the example in your question, since you want `sum([1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1])` to succeed but [3,2,1,2,3,1] is not a permutation of [1,2,3].